# How to change to change color of bottom line in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android) like added attributes in main theme but unable to change color of bottom line in TextInputLayout, by default its taking up color of status bar (its probably called primarydark), also I dont want to change color of bottom line when error text appear below TextInputLayout meaning instead of changing red when error occurs it should be of that color when it gets focus

Comment: have you tried `android:backgroundTint="@color/red(your colour)"` ???

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408295/change-textinputlayout-focused-unfocused-hint-color-programmatically/45409379#45409379)

Comment: i think it will just change the color of bottom line but what about when its focus or when error occures

Answer (score 0):

When there is any error occur and you want to reset your editText and your bottom line color, then just use below code

```
textInputLayout.setError(null);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    textEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color,getTheme()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }else {
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    textEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
```

Comment: what about changing bottom line color when its focus or not